# default value of form control doesn't show

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to give any `formcontrol`'s in my whole project a default value, It doesn't show in the html. Here is an example:

this my ts file

```
 import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, NgForm} from   
 '@angular/forms';

template = this.fb.group({
templateName: ['name', [Validators.required]]})
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
```

my html

```
  <form [formGroup]="template" #formDirective="ngForm" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-con">

          <input matInput placeholder="Template Name"
   maxlength="255" formControlName="templateName" value=""
                 required>
   </form>
```

my module

```
    imports: [
BrowserModule,
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
AppRoutingModule,
RouterModule,
ReactiveFormsModule]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove this attribute `value=""`

```
 <form [formGroup]="template" #formDirective="ngForm" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-con">
     <input matInput placeholder="Template Name"   formControlName="templateName"  >
 </form>
```

> I'm also recommend to remove `maxlength="255",required` and use
>   Validators.required and Validators.maxLength

```
templateName: ['name', [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(255)]]
```